# SAML revalidate user session

Tags: spring, spring-security, saml-2.0, spring-saml

We're implementing SAML using spring-security and PingOne as IdP.
We have an issue, that when user login to the app with SSO, and then is disabled/deleted on IdP, his session is not terminated, so he can continue to use the app.
I've overwrote SAMLAuthenticationProvider authenticate method,so I set expiration date on ExpiringUsernameAuthenticationToken(similar to if IdP gives us SessionNotOnOrAfter value in assertion), but the problem is that user is just logged out from the application, not re-authenticated.

Is there any way to check if user still have active session on IdP side, and only log him out if his IdP session is invalid?

Comment: SAML2 contains a single logout mechanism that can be used to coordinate session lifetime on IDP and SP, but I have no idea if PingOne or spring-security supports it.

Comment: @AndersAbel as I understood, Single Logout works from SP side, when user initiates SL, it logs you out from IdP and SP.

Comment: Single Logout can be initiated both from the SP and from the IDP.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure how to initiate single logout from IdP side, apparently when user is disabled it's not initiated.

Answer (score 0):

for this scenario SAML offers the 'IsPassive' attribute of the AuthnRequest. If set to 'true' this can be used to check if the user still has a valid session with the IdP. Those 'passive' AuthnRequests could be fired on a regular basis (e.g. application side session timeout).

Comment: It would be really cool if Spring Security SAML extension would offer this OOTB. I think this is not the case at the moment.